# React app working in local Host but unable to be deployed to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

My reactjs app works in my localhost but when i try to deploy it to heroku i get an error message saying:

> remote: sh: 1: copy: not found.

Photo of full detailed error message Below.

Package.json Image:
[image: Package.json Image]

Error Message Image:
[image: Error Message Image]

Comment: change `copy` to `cp` in the `build` script

Comment: @wgcrouch Thanks so much, i changed it and there is no more error anymore, but I cant view my application when I click on open app in Heroku. It Shows me the "Heroku | Welcome to your New app page." The Link below is the link to my APP.  https://immense-lowlands-18357.herokuapp.com/  .